# Is it possible to make a program to run automatically after my Remastered Ubuntu installation?

Tags: 16.04, xfce, uck

I'm currently working on my Remastering project for my Assignment. I'm using Ubuntu Customization Kit for this Remastering task and XFCE as Desktop Environment. Is it possible to make a program to be opened after my Remastered Ubuntu installation like Ubuntu Shortcuts list?